# Best way to integrate Browserify into Cordova

Tags: cordova, browserify, cordova-hooks

I was trying to integrate [Browserify](http://browserify.org) into Cordova. I did the following:

- Installed Browserify:
  `npm install -g browserify`
- Moved index.js into the root:
  `mv www/js/index.js .`
- Created a hook script named *appBeforeBuild.sh* which turns *index.js* into *bundle.js*:
  `browserify index.js -o www/js/bundle.js`

  **EDIT - Please see my answer below**
- Updated *config.xml* to run the hook:
  `<hook src="appBeforeBuild.sh" type="before_build" />`
- Updated *index.html* to include *bundle.js* instead of *index.js*:
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>`

This **could be** a nice guide for integrating Browserify into Cordova, but **unfortunately it is not working**, because editing 'index.js' does not trigger a recompile.

> Could anybody please explain how to set index.js into a file which is
>   checked for the **build dependencies** and triggers the **before_build** hook?

Answer (score 0):

The check list in my question is just fine for integrating Browserify into Cordova, but the *[before_build]* script should be corrected. The following is a script suitable for Mac OSX:

**File: appBeforeBuild.sh**

```
echo "[before_build] Start"
b=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S" index.js)
if [ -f timestamp_indexjs.txt ]; then
    a=$(cat timestamp_indexjs.txt)
    if [ $a == $b ]; then
        echo "- No change in index.js"
    else
        echo "- Calling Browserify (timestamp was changed)"
        echo $b>timestamp_indexjs.txt
        browserify index.js -o www/js/bundle.js
    fi
else
    echo "- Calling Browserify (First run, no timestamp)"
    echo $b>timestamp_indexjs.txt
    browserify index.js -o www/js/bundle.js
fi
echo "[before_build] End"
```

This file must be granted with execution rights:

```
chmod +x appBeforeBuild.sh
```

The idea in this script is to make sure that Browserify is called only when *index.js* was changed.

TIPS:

- Put **timestamp_indexjs.txt** into your *.gitignore* file.
- When investigating Cordova issues, run it with `-d` option, as in `cordova -d build android`