# I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require" running a Cordova app on osx

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, require

I am trying to develop a Cordova based app that uses the ytdl-core node module. From my understanding, Cordova uses node-js for running the app on osx (or other non-browser platforms). The app builds successfully and it opens on my Mac, but the javascript won't work since it throws this error on open and/or refresh:

"`modify in config.xml.
2020-05-23 20:11:32.639 Weather[11707:374910] JavaScript error: index.js:11: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`"

index.js:11 is this line: `const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');`

Most people with this error are getting it because browsers do not support "require", but as I said, I'm running on osx platform. I already checked that node.js is installed and the ytdl-core is in the node_modules folder of my project.

Here is my git repository: https://github.com/FCjosh/JRMusicapp.git

I installed cordova exactly as it says on their website with xcode. One more thing worth mentioning is that I am using Jquery although I don't think that is problematic with node.js.

**UPDATE**

After tons of research, I have reason to believe that the reason the Javascript file cannot use the require function is because Cordova is treating it like a browser would. I have three ideas for solutions that may or may not work:

1. Cordova Plugins - A plugin runs natively and perhaps some sort of nodeJS plugin specific to the ytdl dependencies could be made.
2. Browserify, Webpack, or the like. From my understanding, these let you run serverside code on a browser. [This seems pretty straightforward and a likely to work solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134648/best-way-to-integrate-browserify-into-cordova).
3. [Create a native app and embed cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/webviews/index.html). I don't know how to make a native app and if I did, I wouldn't be using Cordova. So I will not pursue this option, but I could understand situations where embedding Cordova in a native app is very useful.

I began making a plugin, but I got stuck when I got to the Objective C part and I have no idea how to implement nodeJS into the plugin. I am changing routes to the Browserify/Webpack solution because the plugin is over my head and making a native app is also over my head.

I will update again soon if the Browserify/Webpack solution works.